# swagger does not work while running app in docker compose

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a basic docker-compose setup to run the SQL server and the app. When I run an application via run with Docker compose it works as expected, automatically opens the browser and redirects to swagger UI. But when running from CLI via `docker compose up --build` it builds db and app and I can see them running in Docker desktop but can't reach out by the given port on docker-compose. Below is the docker-compose file :

```
services:
  app.api:
    container_name: app.api
    image: '${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}appapi'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '5000:80'
    depends_on:
      - app.database
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
  app.database:
    container_name: app.database
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '1433:1433'
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=RSNkHXW1
    volumes:
      - 'sql-data:/var/opt/mssql'
volumes:
  sql-data:
```

I tried to change ports and setting up network inside docker compose but no changes.P.s : I set env to local and in program.cs I check if the env is non-production and add Swagger

Comment: Show us your program/startup and dockerfile lol. Those are telling us what and why happens in terms of route configuration.

But i believe that you might have the line (if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) app.UseSwagger() ... based on default setup configuration

Answer (score 0):

By default, Swagger is only available when your app is running in development mode.

Instead of setting your environment to `Local`, set it to `Development` like this

```
       - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

If you prefer to have Swagger available always, no matter the environment, you can change the code in Program.cs that sets it up.

Comment: in startup.cs I have a piece of code like this :
if (!app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

But it still do not working while running `docker compose up`. It works when I run the app from VS2022 run as Docker Compose

Answer (score 0):

The default docker file generated from visual studio used command like

```
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication98.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
```

"dotnet publish -c `Release`" could be change to "dotnet publish -c `Debug`" to specify the a development image.

You could check the "dotnet publish" configuration from here https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#options